# Cancancan default role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan

I'm building rails app that has some role\abilities separation. I decided to use cancancan + devise, but i can't figure out how to set standard user role?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ROLES = %i[admin moderator author banned]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a callback on your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :assign_default_role

  def assign_default_role
    add_role(:default_role) if self.roles.blank?
  end
end
```

If after_create isn't suitable, try another callback, more info
[here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

Comment: This approach is possible, but actually you don't need to store information about "default role" because it's just user without any roles.

Answer (score 0):

When defining abilities, we use an ability called 'user' for default user permissions. In other words, a user with no other roles gets the default set of abilities.

We also use a set of 'guest' permissions for visitors that are not signed in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following pattern to simplify `Ability` class. Notice, that defining rules for "default" role here is very simple, because it's just signed in user without roles.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    # this is abitilites for anonymous user

    can :read, Post

    return unless user.persisted?

    # ok, now we know that this user is logged in and can define common abilities

    can :create, Post

    # and after it we can define abilities for different roles
    # user.roles here should return name of roles for user, 
    # like [:admin, :moderator]

    user.roles.each { |role| self.public_send(role, user) if respond_to?(role) }
  end

  def admin(user)
    # abitlites for admin here
  end

  def moderator(user)
    # abilities for moderator here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of callback I would set default value on field or in enumeration.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
  field :roles,       type: Array # ,  default: [:am]
  extend Enumerize
  enumerize :roles, in: [:superadmin, :am, :salesrep], multiple: true #,  default: :am
end
```